# Routing via non-database models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a structure where we want to view and edit records, filtered by day. But we want the day to be part of the url

```
 /time_records/day
```

This view shows time_records for a particular day. But when we add a time_record, it needs to redirect back to the same page.

However, it invokes `time_records` without the "day" part in order to call `create`. In order to redirect back to the same page, I think I have to pass a model object to `redirect_to`, but that model would have to be the day itself.

Is the only solution to add a Day object to my model? This seems a bit of a waste as a DateTime is sufficient already logically, this is just about routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With:

```
match '/time_records(/:day)' => 'time_records#show', as: 'time_records'
```

in `routes.rb` you can use the url helper method:

```
time_records_path(day: Date.today)
```

to generate `"/time_records/2011-01-21"`. This works in part because in Rails, Date objects respond to the `to_param` method.

This all assumes you're using ruby 1.9.x and rails 3.0.x

Comment: Hehe, ok. Remember `rake routes` for showing the parsed routeset and feel free to ask about anything that's not clear. I'll attempt to update my answer.